# Elasticsearch:8.7.1 DotNet 7 docker compose for a simple weather api not working

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I am very new to elastic search and I am playing around with the OOB DotNet7 WeatherApi. This is a logging example and I am using **Serilog** and the **Elasticsearch** sink. The versions of elastic search I have tried using are **8.7.1 and 8.10.2** and the outcome of both is the same.
I get the following in my docker logs:

```
Caught exception while performing bulk operation to Elasticsearch: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call.Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product. Call: Status code unknown from: GET
```

I was following youtube tutorial while doing this and apparently it works for the guy but as far as I can tell everything is the same and I cannot get the **Kibana Dashboard** to show logs at all.

I am hosting the sample API code I am working with on a public GitHub repo found **[here](https://github.com/PicBuilder/pbc-webapi-elk)**

Any help on this is appreciated. It seems like something as simple as this should work but I cant figure out where I am messing up.

When I run the command curl http://localhost:9200/ on my Windows machine with power shell U get the following:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {
                      "name" : "a8e6b14cff9e",
                      "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
                      "cluster_uuid" : "7LvJ1XZNx813aV6g",
                      "version" : {
                        "number" : "8.7.1",
                        "build_flavor" : "default",
                        "build_type" ...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-elastic-product: Elasticsearch
                    Content-Length: 539
                    Content-Type: application/json

                    {
                      "name" : "a8e6b14cff9e",
                      "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
                      "cluster_uuid" : "7LvJ1...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[X-elastic-product, Elasticsearch], [Content-Length, 539], [Content-Type, application/json]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 539
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `curl http://localhost:9200/`?

Comment: When i run curl http://localhost:9200/ from my powershell I get the following output (I updated the main post to show the outout of the curl command): StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think elasticsearch Uri is not configured correctly in your app. Try replacing

```
   "ELKConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "default_url"
  },
```

with

```
  "ELKConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://elasticsearch:9200/"
  },
```

if you run your app in a docker-compose or

```
  "ELKConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200/"
  },
```

if you run your app directly in your OS.

I think there also an issue in the docker compose file. It seems that elasticsearch and kibana are sharing the same non-default network and your app is not using the same network:

```
  sampleapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sampleapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/SampleApi/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - elasticnw
```

So, fix the url and networks and see if it work.

Comment: This did it! I also had to update how i was calling the logger in my program.cs as well. but your solution paired with updating the program.cs file, i can see logs information in Kibana. I'll update the repo so it helps anyone else who facing similar issues